# scrollbar for dynamic div using jquery or javascript(for android phonegap)

Tags: jquery, android, cordova, iscroll

I have created application in android phonegap.In my application I have appended list in div dynamically . I want to add scrollbar for dynamic div using iscroll.My code is

Html:

```
  <div class="sidemenu" ></div>
   <div class="searchsidemenu"></div>
```

Style:

```
 #scroller 
 {
 top:90px;
 position:absolute; z-index:1;
 width:90%;
 height:40px;
 background-color:#FFFFFF;
 }
 li
  {
 list-style:none;
 }
```

Script:

- iscroll:

  ```
  var myScroll;
  function loaded() {
      myScroll = new iScroll('scroller', {
          useTransform: false,
          vScroll: true,
          onBeforeScrollStart: function (e) {
              var target = e.target;
              while (target.nodeType != 1) target = target.parentNode;

              if (target.tagName != 'SELECT' && target.tagName != 'INPUT' && target.tagName != 'TEXTAREA')
                  e.preventDefault();
          }
      });
  }
  document.addEventListener('touchmove', function (e) { e.preventDefault(); }, false);
  document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', setTimeout(function () { loaded(); }, 0), false);
  /** scrollbar for dynamic div*/ 
  function doIscrollRefresh () {  
      setTimeout(function () {
          myScroll.refresh();
      }, 0);
  }
  ```

  List 1:- dynamic div (I have retrived value from localdatabase and appended into div dynamically):

  ```
  function list1(alphabet)
  {
        doIscrollRefresh ();
       document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
       function onDeviceReady() 
       {

              var db = window.openDatabase("createdb", "1.0", "PhoneGap Demo", 200000);

              db.transaction(queryDB, errorCB,successCB);

        } 
        function queryDB(tx) 
       {
               var a=alphabet;
               tx.executeSql("SELECT Textvalue FROM TextValue WHERE Textvalue LIKE '" + a + "%'",[], querySuccess, errorCB);
       }

       function querySuccess(tx,results)
        {
             $(".sidemenu").append("<li>"+"<label style='background-color:#C1CDD9' >"+alphabet+ "</label>"+"</li>");
             for (i = 0; i < results.rows.length; i++) 
              {
                   $(".sidemenu").append("<li>"+"<a id='"+i+"'  href='#'>" +results.rows.item(i).Textvalue +  "</a>"+ "<hr/>"+ "</li>");
              }
              $(".sidemenu").append("<hr/>");
         }
    function errorCB(err) 
    {
                alert("Error processing SQL: "+err.code);
    }
    function successCB() 
    {
           //alert("appended");   
    }
  }
  ```

  List 2:- dynamic div (I have retrived value from localdatabase and appended into div dynamically):

  ```
         function retrieveservercauses(arr)
          {

     document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
     function onDeviceReady() 
     {
           var db = window.openDatabase("createdb", "1.0", "PhoneGap Demo", 200000);
           db.transaction(populateDB, errorCB,successCB);
     } 
     function populateDB(tx) 
     {
            tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Name (Name)');
            for(i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
            var arra=arr[i];
            tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO Name (Name)VALUES(?)',[arra]);
            }
     }
     function errorCB(err) 
     {
        //    alert("Error processing SQL: "+err.code);
     }
     function successCB() 
     {
         var db = window.openDatabase("createdb", "1.0", "PhoneGap Demo", 200000);
         db.transaction(queryDB, errorCB);
     }
     function queryDB(tx) 
    {
          var text=$("#searchbox").val();
          tx.executeSql("SELECT * FROM Name WHERE Name LIKE '%" + text + "%'",[], querySuccess1, errorCB);
    }
      function querySuccess1(tx,results) 
      {
          var ar=new Array();
          for (i = 0; i < results.rows.length; i++) 
          {
               var text=$("#searchbox").val();
               var name=results.rows.item(i).Name;
               ar.push(name);
          }
          list2(ar);
          droptextvalue();
          insertTextvalue(text,ar);
      } 
       }

         function list2(ar)
          {

      for(i=0;i<ar.length;i++)
          {

      $(".searchsidemenu").append("<li>"+"<a href='#'>" +ar[i] +"</a>"+"</li>"); 

         }    
           doIscrollRefresh ();
            $(".searchsidemenu").hide();

              }
  ```

  how to add the scrollbar dynamically? It show the error in logcat.the error is myScroll is undefined is not an object. Please tell me the solution.how to addthe scrollbar for dynamic div.please guide me.thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the doIscrollRefresh function is being called before the document finished loading. I can't tell from your code where the list1 function is being called exactly but you should do things is this order:

1: Wait for the document to load so you div exists when you create the scroller (you're doing this already)
2: Create your scroll object.
3: Declare your doIscrollRefresh function after document ready and scroller has been created.
4: Finally after all that fire list1, do your thing.

Try removing doIscrollRefresh at the top of list1 and moving it to querySuccess (like I commented below). Like this:

```
function querySuccess(tx,results)
  {
       $(".sidemenu").append("<li>"+"<label style='background-color:#C1CDD9' >"+alphabet+ "</label>"+"</li>");
       for (i = 0; i < results.rows.length; i++) 
        {
             $(".sidemenu").append("<li>"+"<a id='"+i+"'  href='#'>" +results.rows.item(i).Textvalue +  "</a>"+ "<hr/>"+ "</li>");
        }
        $(".sidemenu").append("<hr/>");
        doIscrollRefresh();
   }
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply.from the document ready i am calling the deviceready for internet connection and from their only i am calling the list1.So where should i call the doIscrollRefresh().kindly guide me.Thanks in Advance

Comment: You're calling onDeviceReady on deviceready, you execute  the doIscrollRefresh before that. Try putting it in querySuccess after you've added your items to the list. I'll update my answer with code.

Comment: thanks for your reply.I have got the scrollbar and the div (sidemenu) containing list is getting scrolled.But I am having two list inside the scroller(another div containing list).So In the second list i got scrollbar but it not getting scrolled.kindly guide me.

Comment: How are you filling the second list? Is there a list2 function? If you add the second list after the first one the iScroll probably needs to be updated again. I suppose adding doIscrollRefresh at a similar position in list2 should fix it then.

Comment: I have tried in the same way as first list.But it not getting scrolled.I have edited my code which includes second list.Kindly guide me.

Comment: This is a guess, but if list2 finished earlier than list1, list1 will refresh iScroll after list2 has been hidden. Does it scroll if you remove the `$(".searchsidemenu").hide();`? You could also try adding `checkDOMChanges: false,` to your iScroll constructor (above `useTransform: false,` for example). I read on the iScroll website this is best practice when using manual refresh().

Comment: In the onload i need to get the sidemenu list and when i make some changes in textbox i need to get the searchsidemenu list.so only i used hide() function.I used like your advice but then also its not getting scrolled.kindly help me.

Comment: I think you have to do the refresh again after you show or update list2 after someone types into the textbox. On a sidenote: If you don't get it to work I think you should accept this answer as a solution to your initial problem (there are scrollbars now) and post this as a new one. The website is starting to complain about the amount of comments. I'm new too but I think we're doing it wrong ;)